# Still seeing welcome to ngnix after setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, capistrano, capistrano3

I have set up and deployed an application using Capistrano and set up the server and ngnix config file, however, I'm still seeing the `Welcome to ngnix` welcome screen.

Here is what I have in the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` file

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

        server_name IP;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env    production;
        root         /home/poladmin/poetry-out-loud-v2/current/public/;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
}
```

But as I said when I go to the server IP all I see is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you edited `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` file, try to reload nginx with `nginx -s reload` command (if you are using Linux, or similar depending on your operating system and nginx version).

Answer (score 0):

As you have edited the nginx config file you can try to restart nginx by doing `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart`to make the config file take effort. Also do not forget to start the real ruby server and make sure it is listening to the same port you configured through nginx.(some times the ruby app may be running on a different port)